# Cant get Jquery to remove and add class on browser resize correctly

Tags: jquery

can't seem to get my jquery working the way im trying to get it to.

I'm using font-awesome for my icons.

Basically, I want my "hamburger" menu to change to a "X" symbol on browser resize so people can hide there menu if they would like even at larger screens.

The problem is if i leave the jquery code the way it was, it would show a hamburger menu at larger screens, and when clicking to hide the menu, it would show a x. I basically want the opposite on larger display. Show the X first on larger displays to "hide the menu" and then the bar to they car show it again.

Here is my code. (stripped and altered to be as simple as possible)

```
<div class="nav-bar">
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="menu-text">Hide </span>Menu</li>
      <li><a name="ham-menu" id="ham-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS >

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-text {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  .drop-menu span {
            display: inline;
        }
  }
}
```

JQUERY >

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      /* DROP DOWN MENU AND TOGGLE CSS CLASS TO CHANGE 3 BAR ICON TO X ICON ON CLICK */
      var $window = $(window),
            $hamMenu = $('#ham-menu i'),
          $nav = $('nav');

      $('#ham-menu').on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        //$('nav').fadeToggle();
        $hamMenu.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-close');
        $nav.slideToggle();
      });


     /* CODE THAT CHANGES THE 3 BAR MENU ICON TO A "X" ICON ON BROWSER RESIZE PAST 500PX */

      function resize() {
    if($window.width() >= 500) {
        return $hamMenu.removeClass('fa-bars');
    } 
        $hamMenu.addClass('fa-close');
    }

    $window
        .resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');

      }); /* END JQUERY */
```

My onclick event works just fine when its by itself. It drops the NAV menu down and changes the 3 bar menu to an X.

The issue is when I add in the 2nd part of the code that changes the 3 bar icon to an X when the browser is greater than a certain width. I want to give the user the ability to close the menu if they desire to even on a larger display if they have JS enabled.

When i added in the resize function that I found in another post here on SO, if totally glitches up my menu and it doesn't work right at all.

Here is the nav menu working fine with the 2nd part of my jquery removed.

[Working navigation drop down](https://jsfiddle.net/bbw3mwr2/2/)

Here is the menu not working at all when I try to add in the code to switch the bar to a X icon on larger displays.

[Navigation not working anymore](https://jsfiddle.net/bbw3mwr2/3/)

The icon does have an X at larger displays, but then there isn't a 3 bar icon anymore at the mobile size. When I click on the 3 bar icon on mobile, it completely removes it and doesn't show the X icon anymore. You'll see what I mean when you look at the fiddle. I'm probably missing something really easy.

How do i get the Icon to change back to a 3 bar icon on mobile view. I'm lost.

---

### Update 1 >

---

Here is the working code, much simpler than I thought it would be.

```
  $('#ham-menu').on('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        //$('nav').fadeToggle();
        $hamMenu.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-close');
        $nav.slideToggle();
    });

    /* CHANGE OUT THE 3 BAR MENU TO CROSS TO START WITH ON NAV MENU TO ALLOW USER TO CLOSE THE MENU */
    if ($window.width() > 750) {
        return $hamMenu.toggleClass('fa-close fa-bars');
    }
```

This works perfectly it someone was to load up the browser at different widths. Let's say i wanted to have it so the classes "switched" by taking the browser and manually changing the width of it, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Should your resize event handler be an if / else, or do you always want to re-add the fa-close class?

Comment: I am not sure, new to jquery lol. When the display is larger than 500, i want the 3 bar icon (fa-bars) to change to a X icon (fa-close). And then when clicking the X icon, it toggles between the fa-close and fa-bars icons. It works without the browser resize function in mobile just fine, but when i added the function resize code, it messed everything up, can't seem to figure out how to get it working right.

Comment: Your applying the fa-bars to the element in markup. The resize event handler is adding the fa-close class (but not removing the fa-bars class for smaller display sizes). Once the user clicks on the icon, both classes are removed as a result of the toggle, which is why neither icon is visible. If you replace your resize event handler with the same line of javascript that toggles both classes, I think that solves your problem

Comment: I think i read to much into a tutorial i was following on here, this helped, thank you for reply! :). 

This works perfectly if i "refresh" the browser at different widths now. Is there a way i can have it change out the classes when resizing the browser rather than just having to refresh it at a different size? Updating my original question.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question, the window resize event handler you wrote should be being invoked whenever the browser size changes, you shouldn't have to refresh the page. Maybe you could update your js fiddle to demonstrate the problem? Also, please mark my answer as correct so that other people having similar problems will be more likely to read it. It may sound silly but I'm trying to establish a good reputation on SO. The number of points someone has on their peofile is the type of thing that some recruiters use when considering a candidate's resume. Thanks